# Why use make() to create a slice in Go?

Tags: go

- What is the difference between `var a [4]int` and `b := make([]int, 4)`? The `b` can be extended, but not `a`, right? But if I know that I need really i.e. 4 elements, then is an array faster then a slice?
- Is there any performance difference between `var d []int` and `e := make([]int)`? Would `f := make([]int, 5)` provide more performance than without the length for the first i.e. 5 elements?
- Would this `c := make([]int, 5, 10)` not allocate more memory than I can access?

Comment: `e := make([]int)` is invalid. It requires the length argument for a slice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `a` is an array, and `b` is a slice. What makes slices different from arrays is that a slice is a pointer to an array; slices are reference types, which means that if you assign one slice
  to another, both refer to the same underlying array. For instance, if a function takes a
  slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be visible to the caller,
  analogous to passing a pointer to the underlying array(Above from [Learning Go](http://www.miek.nl/projects/learninggo/)). You can easily use `append` and `copy` with slice. Array should be a little faster than slice, but it doesn't make much difference. Unless you know the size exactly, it would be better to use slice which make things easy.
- make([]type,length, capacity), you can estimate the size and possible capacity to improve the performance.

More details, you can refer:[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/2011/01/go-slices-usage-and-internals.html)